# Android Studio - OpenCV project wont build

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, gradle

I followed the instructions to import OpenCV to Android Studio here https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/opencv-android, after Android Studio wouldn't let me use the File > New > Import Module feature. After following the instructions, I get these build errors:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> com.android.manifmerger.ManifestMerger2$MergeFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: H:\AndroidProjects\WyzeCloud\Rev1\IPCloud\app\build\intermediates\navigation_json\debug\navigation.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
> ============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction
> H:\AndroidProjects\WyzeCloud\Rev1\IPCloud\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out
> ============================================================================

BUILD FAILED in 18s

Anyone know what these errors mean, or have a possible solution to importing OpenCV to an Android Studio project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem before and my solution:
Download the Android sdk of Open-CV from this link: https://opencv.org/releases/
Add the java and jni library files into your project. Java functions of this library is works with jni files (.so).